# Spinning thread barrier using Atomic Builtins

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, compare-and-swap, barrier

I'm trying to implement a spinning thread barrier using atomics, specifically __sync_fetch_and_add. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

I basically want an alternative to the pthread barrier. I'm using Ubuntu on a system that can run about a hundred threads in parallel.

```
int bar = 0;                      //global variable
 int P = MAX_THREADS;              //number of threads

 __sync_fetch_and_add(&bar,1);     //each thread comes and adds atomically
 while(bar<P){}                    //threads spin until bar increments to P
 bar=0;                            //a thread sets bar=0 to be used in the next spinning barrier
```

This does not work for obvious reasons (a thread may set bar=0, and another thread gets stuck in an infinite while loop etc). I saw an implementation here: Writing a (spinning) thread barrier using c++11 atomics, however it seems too complex and I think its performance might be worse than a pthread barrier.

This implementation is also expected to produce more traffic within the memory hierarchy due to bar's cache line being ping-ponged among threads.

Any ideas on how to use these atomic instructions to make a simple barrier? A communication-optimal scheme would also be helpful additionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of spinning on *the counter of the threads*, it is better to spin on *the number of the barries passed*, which will be incremented only by the last thread, faced the barrier. Such way you also reduce memory cache pressure, as spinning variable is now updated only by single thread.

```
int P = MAX_THREADS;
int bar = 0; // Counter of threads, faced barrier.
volatile int passed = 0; // Number of barriers, passed by all threads.

void barrier_wait()
{
    int passed_old = passed; // Should be evaluated before incrementing *bar*!

    if(__sync_fetch_and_add(&bar,1) == (P - 1))
    {
        // The last thread, faced barrier.
        bar = 0;
        // *bar* should be reseted strictly before updating of barriers counter.
        __sync_synchronize(); 
        passed++; // Mark barrier as passed.
    }
    else
    {
        // Not the last thread. Wait others.
        while(passed == passed_old) {};
        // Need to synchronize cache with other threads, passed barrier.
        __sync_synchronize();
    }
}
```

Note, that you need to use `volatile` modificator for spinning variable.

C++ code could be somewhat faster than C one, as it can use *acquire*/*release* memory barriers instead of the *full* one, which is the only barrier available from `__sync` functions:

```
int P = MAX_THREADS;
std::atomic<int> bar = 0; // Counter of threads, faced barrier.
std::atomic<int> passed = 0; // Number of barriers, passed by all threads.

void barrier_wait()
{
    int passed_old = passed.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

    if(bar.fetch_add(1) == (P - 1))
    {
        // The last thread, faced barrier.
        bar = 0;
        // Synchronize and store in one operation.
        passed.store(passed_old + 1, std::memory_order_release);
    }
    else
    {
        // Not the last thread. Wait others.
        while(passed.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == passed_old) {};
        // Need to synchronize cache with other threads, passed barrier.
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }
}
```