# What is wrong with this implementation of Barrier using atomics in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, barrier

I've wrote the following implementation of a Barrier using atomics only:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

pub struct Barrier {
  pub done: AtomicUsize,
  pub tids: usize,
}

impl Barrier {
  pub fn new(tids: usize) -> Barrier {
    Barrier {
      done: AtomicUsize::new(0),
      tids,
    }
  }

  pub fn wait(&self) {
    let done = self.done.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
    if done + 1 == self.tids {
      self.done.store(0, Ordering::SeqCst);
    } else {
      while self.done.load(Ordering::SeqCst) != 0 {}
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't work as expected. For example,

```
// inside threads loop
barrier.wait();
println!("a");
barrier.wait();
println!("b");
```

Intuitively, it should work, since, once `.wait()` is called, it will hang on the `while` loop, breaking free from it after all the threads have called `.wait()`, and resetting the counter for the next `.wait()`. Instead, eventually it will hang. Below is an usage example:

```rust
fn main() {
  println!("Hello, world!");

  let barrier = &Barrier::new(10);

  std::thread::scope(|s| {
    for tid in 0 .. 10 {
      s.spawn(move || {
        loop {
          barrier.wait();
          println!("{} a", tid);
          barrier.wait();
          println!("{} b", tid);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @cafce25 added an usage example and fixed an issue on the question.

Comment: Edit: oh, I can see the issue now. It will hang because the a thread may increment the counter for the next `.wait()` before another thread escapes from the loop. Silly. I'll leave the question open though.

Comment: @cafce25 I will, once I figure out the solution

Comment: Yes, exactly that is the problem. One iteration and the next could mix, one fast thread could block another thread from a previous iteration. It's not guaranteed that all threads actually get released properly.

Comment: If you always use the same threads, you could solve this by having a second 'done' counter and flipping back and forth between the two between iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is a race condition between two consecutive barriers:

- A thread might get unscheduled while waiting for the barrier.
- A second thread (who is the last thread the barrier waits for) enters the barrier, releases it, runs its next iteration and enters the barrier again
- The first thread wakes up and sees a value of `1`, missing the barrier release completely.

If you are sure that you are always using the same threads, you could fix that by utilizing two counters, and flipping back and forth between them. That way all threads wait either for the first or the second one. But there is no way for one thread to bypass the others, as it would have to go through the second counter to block the first one again, and the second one will only unblock if no thread is still left in the first one.

This one seems to work:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, AtomicUsize, Ordering};

pub struct Barrier {
    pub done: [AtomicUsize; 2],
    pub use_first_done: AtomicBool,
    pub tids: usize,
}

impl Barrier {
    pub fn new(tids: usize) -> Barrier {
        Barrier {
            done: [AtomicUsize::new(0), AtomicUsize::new(0)],
            use_first_done: AtomicBool::new(true),
            tids,
        }
    }

    pub fn wait(&self) {
        let done = if self.use_first_done.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            &self.done[0]
        } else {
            &self.done[1]
        };

        let num_done = done.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst) + 1;
        if num_done == self.tids {
            self.use_first_done.fetch_xor(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
            done.store(0, Ordering::SeqCst);
        } else {
            while done.load(Ordering::SeqCst) != 0 {}
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let barrier = &Barrier::new(10);

    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        for tid in 0..10 {
            s.spawn(move || loop {
                barrier.wait();
                println!("{} a", tid);
                barrier.wait();
                println!("{} b", tid);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

---

An alternative would be to use an iteration counter.

For the same reason as why flipping between two `done` counters works, an iteration counter of two iterations (= a boolean) should be sufficient.

This one works for me as well:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, AtomicUsize, Ordering};

pub struct Barrier {
    pub done: AtomicUsize,
    pub iteration: AtomicBool,
    pub tids: usize,
}

impl Barrier {
    pub fn new(tids: usize) -> Barrier {
        Barrier {
            done: AtomicUsize::new(0),
            iteration: AtomicBool::new(false),
            tids,
        }
    }

    pub fn wait(&self) {
        let iteration = self.iteration.load(Ordering::SeqCst);
        let num_done = self.done.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst) + 1;
        if num_done == self.tids {
            self.done.store(0, Ordering::SeqCst);
            self.iteration.fetch_xor(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
        } else {
            while iteration == self.iteration.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {}
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let barrier = &Barrier::new(10);

    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        for tid in 0..10 {
            s.spawn(move || loop {
                barrier.wait();
                println!("{} a", tid);
                barrier.wait();
                println!("{} b", tid);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** This only works if the threads are always identical. If different threads use this barrier, then it's necessary to have a bigger iteration counter.

Comment: Looks really good, thank you. I ended up designing [this version](https://gist.github.com/VictorTaelin/554af97959a2fbed0a8869f18561c69f) based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598686/spinning-thread-barrier-using-atomic-builtins). It uses an additional variable to count the total number of wait's passed, preventing interference. I believe your answer is more robust.

Comment: @MaiaVictor In your gist, `pass` could overflow, causing a panic. So a wrapping add would fix that. Apart of that, I think it's fine. I added a second solution which kind of uses your gist, but only uses a bool iteration counter.

Answer (score 2):

I like the @Finomnis solution. I also, want to improve it a little bit. Please consider my changes too.

```
pub struct Barrier {
    pub done: AtomicUsize,
    pub iteration: AtomicBool,
    pub tids: usize,
}

impl Barrier {
    pub fn new(tids: usize) -> Barrier {
        Barrier {
            done: AtomicUsize::new(0),
            iteration: AtomicBool::new(false),
            tids,
        }
    }

    pub fn wait(&self) {
┌-----┬ let iteration = self.iteration.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
|     | let num_done = self.done.fetch_add(1, Ordering::AcqRel) + 1;
|     | if num_done == self.tids {
|     └->   self.done.store(0, Ordering::Relaxed);
|           self.iteration.fetch_xor(true, Ordering::AcqRel);
X           return;
|        }
|
└-----> // let iteration = self.iteration.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
        // Instruction couldn't be moved here because we have a request to 
        // see all memory changes self.iteration.fetch_xor with 
        // AcqRel ordering. It's safe to use here Relaxed ordering.

        // For example, we could imagine that Acquire-Release ordering is 
        // like a sandwich.
   ┌----- ...instructions, could be moved inside of a sandwich
   |      Acquire
   ├----->  
   |      Release
   └-X--> ...instructions, but not here.


        // Cares only for changes in self.iteration
        // Let's use here the lowest memory ordering
        while iteration == self.iteration.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
            // I think that there could be saved a few CPU cycles if we give 
            // a compiler a hint that it's a waiting loop.
            // Note: It's a Clippy suggestion.
            std::hint::spin_loop();

            // Also, could be used yield, but is better to use a hint
            // std::thread::yield_now();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! I'm still having problems grasping the different memory ordering hints. I'm glad they already dropped two compared to C++, but it's still confusing to me :D.
I didn't know about the `spin_loop` hint! That one is cool, thanks. I prefer if-else over if-return, though. But that's probably personal preference.

Comment: Very cool! Hadn't seen this answer before. For the waiting hint, I use crossbeam's Backoff: https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/utils/struct.Backoff.html