How do I thread safely write a struct to memory?
I have a basic struct consisting of only atomics:
#[repr(C)]
struct Chunk {
    size: AtomicU32,
    flags: AtomicU32,
    prev: AtomicPtr<Chunk>
}

At some point I need to create structs like this in raw memory.
Example:
(p as *mut Chunk).write(Chunk {
    size: AtomicU32::new((size + size_of::<Chunk>()) as u32),
    flags: AtomicU32::new(0),
    prev: AtomicPtr::default() });


I have a lock for the memory section so writing is fine but I wondered if the write could end up in the cache and the propagation to the other caches happens then at a "random" time, potentially after releasing the lock. Or is this solved by the struct members being atomic and all loads with Ordering::Acquire are already syncing the memory?
(The lock is just an atomicbool; I manually implement locking using compare_exchange to "acquire the lock".  Editor's note: and hopefully a release store to unlock, to make a spinlock.)
What is a potential way to avoid that without the use of a memory fence and without using most libraries (even simple ones / inbuilt ones are mostly of limit, as I have no allocator available so everything which uses the heap just crashes).
Should I create the struct in memory and then initialize each member with an atomic store?
I am open to most suggestions and critics regarding my memory handling.

If you hold a lock during all accesses to the memory (reads and writes) then you don't need atomics at all.

It's not a real lock, it is just an atomicbool somewhere which I compare_exchange to "acquire the lock".

But in general, releasing a lock is a release barrier (hence the name), so all preceding accesses are forced to be globally visible before the lock appears as unlocked to other threads.

If you do an acquire compare-exchange to acquire the lock, and a release store to release it, then it is a real lock.  That's the same semantics that any mutex has - the only improvement offered by a mutex is to be able to wait efficiently when the lock is unavailable.

Ah I thought atomic loads/stores are memory address specific and not all memory? Does the whole cache get flushed with a release store?

It's nothing to do with flushing caches; this is a pervasive misconception.  See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746793/does-a-memory-barrier-ensure-that-the-cache-coherence-has-been-completed.  The L1 cache is coherent, thanks to MESI protocol or the like; as soon as a store commits to L1 cache, it is immediately visible to all other threads, no flushing of any kind needed.

I need atomic because it is essentially a linked list, without a general lock. The lock described here is only for the last link, so that only a single thread adds a new link.

What a release store will typically do is to drain the store buffer, which is local to the core and holds stores that are still waiting for their cache line to become owned by this core.  But yes, it drains it of all stores that were inserted earlier in program order.

Thanks for that link, was a nice read. But what I didn't gather from it: Is the store buffer drain guaranteed for x86-64 and arm64 on release storing any atomic?

Yes.  That's how we get release semantics.  On x86, store buffer entries commit in program order, meaning that every store is automatically release.  On arm64, store buffer entries can commit out of order, but stlr inserts a barrier, so it won't commit until after all earlier stores have done so.  (So it doesn't literally have to drain the store buffer competely; if there are entries corresponding to stores that are later in program order, it's fine for them to stay there.)

@NateEldredge: https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ is a good explanation of the ordering a release-store or acquire-load have.  I often link, since Jeff Preshing's articles (including that one) helped me get an understanding of memory order in terms of how CPUs actually work.

@Lantanar I would also recommend my answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/74680794/3324341) to take a look. It will explain how atomic operations force to be seen, and where CPU could reorder them.
